# JS - Interrupt async execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation

### The actual Problem

The problem I am trying to solve is that a user may not provide enough information on a message (discord). To then get all of the necessary data the user is prompted to react to a bot message.
There are 3 stages of that bot message, "InitialPrompt", "TimeoutWarning" and "TimeoutSuccess(TicketFailure)".

### What I wanted the solution to be

With the way I've written my code there is no way to abort the timeout after it has been initialized. I thought that throwing an error would stop the execution of a function. I guess that doesn't happen because async calls get queued up instead of being ran line by line.

Is there a way to do this without adding a boolean and checking infront of each function call?

#### The solution that I could come up with

```js
const interPtr = {interrupted : false};
interruptSignal(interPtr);

if(interPtr.interrupted) return;
console.log("...");
...
```

### The actual code

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/4zojk2tn/)

```js
(async () => {
  const sleep = async time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

  const interruptSignal = () => new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    console.log("interruptStarted")
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log("interruptRan");
    throw "Interrupted"
  });
  

  const timeOutHandler = async () => {
    interruptSignal();
    console.log("TimeoutStarted")
    await sleep(5000);
    console.log("TimeoutWarning")
    await sleep(5000);
    console.log("TimeoutSuccess->TicketFailure")
  };

  try {
    await timeOutHandler();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  
})()
```

Comment: You cannot achieve that.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! You'd want just `async () => {` instead of `() => new Promise(async (res, rej) => {`. (But no, that doesn't solve your problem, the `interruptSignal();` promise is still not awaited and won't interrupt the execution of `timeoutHandler`).

Comment: "*Is there a way to do this without adding a boolean and checking infront of each function call?*" - no, not really. Checking for an `isInterrupted` or `isCancelled` flag is still the way to go.

Comment: @Bergi I see why I was using Promises in a wrong way, my bad. Thank you for pointing that out (this is actually the first time I tried to do something like that ). I was trying out more things =>  https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/4zojk2tn/7/, would you know why "TimeoutWarning" still runs, despite `lock` having failed already ?

Comment: @Twiggeh Because you're still calling `func()` which logs the output, and only after that the `Promise.race` notices that the `lock` is rejected. I would recommend not to use a promise in `createLock` and `Promise.race` for the executing, but simple boolean flags like you had in mind originally. And actually you'll need to race the `sleep(5000)` with the `lock`, if that is what you want to get interrupted.